# setState react hook for array is not saving prior array elements

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, use-state

I have an API request that uses aysnc and await, grabs the data, then makes a second request with Promise.all, which makes multiple API requests with the id's. That part works out fine.

However, when I go to save the data inside a React hook called, "setItem", it only saves that one and over writes the others. I have a spread operator inside the setItem()

setItems(...items, data)

data being the response from the API request.

My API request is in the top layer of my react app, so I pulled it out into it's own little helper file, that's why "items" and "setItems", are arguments passed through.

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import BottleNeck from 'bottleneck'

    const limiter = new BottleNeck({
      maxConcurrent: 1, 
      minTime: 333
    })

    export const Request = (items, setItems) => {

      const getData = () => {
        const options = 'newstories' 
        const API_URL = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/${options}.json?print=pretty`;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          return resolve(axios.get(API_URL))
        })
      }

      const getIdFromData = (dataId) => {
        const API_URL = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${dataId}.json?print=pretty`;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          return resolve(axios.get(API_URL))
        })
      }

      const runAsyncFunctions = async () => {
        const {data} = await getData()

        Promise.all(
          data.map(async (d) => {
            const {data} = await limiter.schedule(() => getIdFromData(d))
           //****************** issue here ************************//
            setItems([...items, data]);
          })
        )
      }
      runAsyncFunctions()

    }
```

just in case you want to see the app.js file for reference

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import { SearchBar } from './search-bar';
    import { Results } from './results';
    import { Request } from './helper/request'

    function App() {
      const [input, setInput] = useState('');
      const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

      const handleChange = val => {
        setInput(val)
      }
      // console.log(input)
      // console.log(results)

      // API calls
      // call useEffect here, calls Request(), put results in useEffect

      useEffect(() => {
        Request(items, setItems)
      }, [])

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar handleChange={handleChange}/>
          <Results items={items} />
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but I don't see `results` actually defined anywhere or used in your helper file. Can you confirm if `...results` ever evaluates to something with console log or similar?

Comment: im sorry, let me edit that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your `Promise.all` return each data, after you can chain with `then` that passes an array with all resolved data. This way you only need to call it once `setItems`:

```
Promise.all(
  data.map(async (d) => {
    const { data } = await limiter.schedule(() => getIdFromData(d));
    return data;
  })
).then((dataResults) => setItems((results) => [...results, ...dataResults]));
```

Comment: thank you that was helpful, however after implementing the '.then' method and what you describe, when i console.log(results) in the app component to get state, it now just shows an empty array. as if nothing is loading

Comment: yea youre right and i realize that, i edited it in the description (because of another persons comment, to make things clearer). but it still does not show anything in state...

Comment: i think the problem is, it's waiting to load the whole array of API calls. which is 500. sooo it'd be awhile before i see it in state. would there be a way where I can stop it after 5 or 10 calls, thus 5 or 10 objects in the array?

Comment: yup, confirmed it. it showed in state after the Promise.all completed all 500 calls. I guess the next question would be how to split it up into arrays of ten, or more so, do I split it up before the Promise.all fires off

Comment: It would require a more refined approach, some sort of pagination where you can break the requests as needed